# How do I make thumb nails lead to files

Tags: php, html, flash, web

I'm making a flash game portal I've figured out how to upload files With php and how to display them with the object tag in HTML but I need to know how to let the user upload thumb nails and have those thumb nails lead to the game.

I looked everywhere but all I can find is image gallery's that can't be modified to to what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure of how you list these items, but it sounds like you want to make an HTML link using an image as the link.

```
<a href="target"><img src="img target"></a>
```

would create a link image.

Comment: I did that but if you link directly to the .swf file it opens full screen what I want is to open the file in a small window like you can with the object tag so that I can show things like views and comments I try'd to generate each games web page when it uploaded but then if I want to update the site i will have to delete all the games

Comment: I don't know how you've coded your site, but the general approach to this would be to have a $_GET link system with PHP, where every game has a unique ID, so that when you browse for example yoursite.com?game=1, it would load a specific game. If that's how it's currently set up, you would simply have to point a link the way I showed you to that. You can't link an object directly. You could however try to dynamically generate the object using jQuery.

Comment: How do I give the game an I'd do you mean with a SQL database if so how do the id's corspond to the game thumb nail file. And what mean by dynamically generate the objects using jquery I don't know much jquery

Comment: How are games currently loaded? Are they hard-coded in a file, or are they fetched from a SQL database? If they are fetched from the database, I'd suggest adding a field to that table for the thumbnail, and then fetch the ID of the row when a user clicks a thumbnail.

Comment: They are hard coded in a file I didn't known you cold store file in a SQL data base. The way I'm currently working on is to store info about the game in a database like its .swf file name and its thumb nails name and useing a for each loop to crate a thumb nail for each row then have the thumb nail leed to a page with a object tag that displays the game but  I don't known how to make it show a diffrent game depending on wich thumb nail was clicked I think I can do this by storeing the file name in the session data by then the user cold not bookmark or link to the page do you know a better way

Comment: Your idea to store the .swf (perhaps along with the name of the game and the thumbnail image name) in a database that you loop through and display to the user is a solid idea. The easiest way to solve your problem is to make sure that each game has a unique ID in the database (make a column called id, make it auto increment). You'd then as I suggested make thumbnail images leading to (for example) ?game=id, and check using `$_GET` if the user is looking at a link like that. If he is, retrieve the game from the database and display it to the user.

Comment: that sounds like it would work but how do i use $_GET to get data form a MySQL database and how do i carry data form the page with the thumbnails to the page that displays the game

Comment: Use the GET to fetch that specific row from the database. I don't know how to explain it differently if that doesn't make sense to you. Read up on GET on php.net

Comment: ive read the documentation on get but when i use it on a variable and not on a form it say's Undefined index

Comment: `$test = $_GET["cool"];` would contain "icecream" If the URL is http://yoursite.tld/file.php?cool=icecream

Comment: that assigns $test to the data in a input field but if i try to get data form a varbail
like this 

$test = 'icecraem';
$_GET["$test"]; 

it say's Undefined index: icecraem

Comment: You fetch data from forms with $_POST as long as the form method is POST. Know that I'm strictly talking about the variables here. Whether or not you use them in a form is irrelevant.

Comment: i don't think were on the same page here. the user dose not type the name ove the file in a input field they click on a thumb nail and since the .swf file name is in the same row as the thumb nail it selects the game file but if you just send the browser to the game file it opens full screen but i want it in a object tag so that i can show thing like views and comment. i was thinking ove doing this by storing the game name in the session data but then the user would not be able to bookmark or link to the page

Comment: Right, so when you're selecting thumbnails (presumably thumbnail and the swf) from the database, make the query select the ID of that row as well (and if it doesn't have one, create a column named ID as I stated before and make it auto increment). Then make it so thumbnails are instead linked to ?game=unique id - and upon loading that page (which you check if the user is by using $_GET) you load the content belonging to that ID, that being the swf.

If that is not a good enough explanation, then I'm sorry - I can't explain it better.

Comment: thanks i never though ove using $_GET like that it works grate

Comment: Glad to help! Hope your website becomes successful!